# Can I get simple name resolution on the local network without DNS, on a Mac?

Tags: networking, samba, domain-name-system

I've got Mantis running on a Linux VM with a Win2k8 server host. I installed Samba with the following configuration:

```
[global]
workgroup = COMPANY
netbios name = MANTIS
security = share
```

Now on all our windows machines people can simple go to http://mantis, rather than http://172.16.0.20.
However, this doesn't appear to work on the Mac machines.

Any ideas how I can sort this without changing anything on the Windows server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-get install avahi
```

will install a m-dns service.

you macs should then be able resolve your server via zeroconf (mdns)

have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Does the Mac support a /etc/hosts lookup file like full-blown BSD machines do?

Comment: Of course it does like every Unix/Windows etc. System, but you would have to enter it in every hosts file on every machine which makes it kind of hard to do, and especially for Laptops which might be on a different Network from time to time, doing name resolution that way is not a good idea. The way to go is Bonjour/Zerocong/mDNS whatever you call it ;)

Comment: I'm not a fan of Bonjour, it seems to be very chatty.  Thought was that for just one stray Mac that a hosts entry would be acceptable.